# dotnet publish -c Release to a self contained exe doesn't work

Tags: c#, exe

So i made an app in C#, visual studio 2019, and i wanted it to run from a single EXE file, so i added

```
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

to the .csproj file, used `dotnet publish -c Release` and it made the standalone exe, but it just crashes on startup. Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Turns out i was an idiot and used the experimental (at least for now) .NET Core 5.0. Thank you all for all your ideas, i leared a lot!

Comment: Can you tell us what error message you're getting? I've tried reproducing your problem by creating a new console app with your settings but it works just fine, so it should have something to do with your code.

Comment: The problem is, i don't get an error message. It tells me it was succesful, but when i run it, it crashes as soon as i open it up

Comment: Nvm, i was using .NET Core 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this in my buildserver;

```
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  runtime: 'win-x64'

...

dotnet publish -c $(BuildConfiguration) -o $(Build.StagingDirectory)/ci-build --no-build --self-contained -r $(runtime)
```

You shouldn't call --no-build however, unless you've already done so already.

Try if this works and else ill remove this.

Comment: Nope, still nothing

Comment: Nvm, i was using .NET Core 5.0

Comment: What's the problem with .net 5.0 ??

Comment: Oh, back then it was an experimental version and very broken